# saving clipboard takes forever on quit

Tags: spacemacs, clipboard

When closing spacemacs, I get the message "Saving clipboard to x clipboard manager...". The saving process ends up taking so much time that I have to kill emacs from the terminal. How can I disable emacs from doing this process upon quitting? Or at least how can I figure out what emacs function is responsible for displaying this message?

Answer (score 2):

As the message says:

> Saving clipboard to x clipboard manager...

Try `emacs -Q` and copy then close emacs, you get this message:

> Error saving to X clipboard manager.
>
> If the problem persists, set 'x-select-enable-clipboard-manager' to nil.

So add `(setq x-select-enable-clipboard-manager nil)` to your .emacs file